# Changing field in a table from form in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Sorry if this is a newbie question, I'm a bit rusty in Access and even more rusty in Visual Basic!

I'm trying to find a way of changing a field in a table when a field in another (unrelated) form is changed. More specifically, I'm after a way of reducing the number in the table by whatever the value is in the form field (in a stock control way)

Does anybody know the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: This is a bad idea. You're making data in one table dependent on data in another and there's no way to insure that the dependent value is correct (though A2010 is going to offer table-level data macros that can be used like triggers to insure that this happens at the db engine level).

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "You're making data in one table dependent on data in another and there's no way to insure that the dependent value is correct" -- what about an inter-table CHECK constraint to ensure the values don't get out of synch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is probably an update query run via VBA, for example:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL as String

Set db=CurrentDB

strSQL="UPDATE Stock SET InStock=Instock-" & Me.OrderQty & " WHERE ID=" & Me.ID

db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

MsgBox "Updated " & db.RecordsAffected & " record(s)"
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks
Most of it works a treat except for one small problem
I've changed OrderQty to be the name of the textbox, but I'm finding it's set as the old value inside the textbox (for example if it was 2 and I changed it to 3, 3 would be returned)

Google isn't being much help here sadly :(

Comment: Nevermind, managed to find http://www.utteraccess.com/forums/showflat.php?Board=83&Number=1891516 and fix it. For anybody else who might get this problem, it seems I had to change focus to another object and back again and that would read the new value.

Thanks again for your help, remou!